# Volley Authorization Required

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert Unirest

```
   HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("https://api.tap.company/v2/charges")
  .header("authorization", "Bearer sk_test_XKokBfNWv6FIYuTMg5sLPjhJ")
  .header("content-type", "application/json")
  .body("{\"amount\":1,\"currency\":\"KWD\",\"receipt\":{\"email\":false,\"sms\":true},\"customer\":{\"first_name\":\"test\",\"phone\":{\"country_code\":\"965\",\"number\":\"50000000\"}},\"source\":{\"id\":\"src_kw.knet\"},\"redirect\":{\"url\":\"http://your_website.com/redirect_url\"}}")
  .asString();
```

to Volley

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        String url = "https://api.tap.company/v2/charges";
        StringRequest TapREQUEST = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.w("OnResponse:", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { error.printStackTrace(); }
        }) {
            @Override public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("content-type", "application/json");
                headers.put("authorization", "Bearer sk_test_XKokBfNWv6FIYuTMg5sLPjhJ");
                //String auth = "Bearer " + Base64.encodeToString("sk_test_XKokBfNWv6FIYuTMg5sLPjhJ".getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                //headers.put("authorization", auth);
                return headers;
            }
            @Override protected Map<String,String> getParams() {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("amount", String.valueOf(9.500));
                params.put("currency","KWD");
                params.put("receipt","{'email':false,'sms':true}");
                params.put("customer",":{'first_name':'test','phone':{'country_code':'965','number':'50000000'}}");
                params.put("source","{'id':'src_kw.knet'}");
                params.put("redirect",":{'url':'http://ib7ar.com'}");
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(TapREQUEST);
```

but I get
E/Volley: [396] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://api.tap.company/v2/charges

When I click on link I get

> {"errors":[{"code":"2107","description":"Authorization Required"}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set body parameters in different way. Let's create method returning correct string:

```
@NotNull
private JSONObject getJsonObject() {
    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    try {
        params.put("amount", "1");
        params.put("currency", "KWD");

        JSONObject receipt = new JSONObject();
        receipt.put("email", "false");
        receipt.put("sms", "true");
        params.put("receipt", receipt);

        JSONObject customer = new JSONObject();
        customer.put("first_name", "test");
        JSONObject phone = new JSONObject();
        phone.put("country_code", "965");
        phone.put("number", "50000000");
        customer.put("phone", phone);
        params.put("customer", customer);

        JSONObject id = new JSONObject();
        id.put("id", "src_kw.knet");
        params.put("source", id);

        JSONObject url = new JSONObject();
        url.put("url", "http://ib7ar.com");

        params.put("redirect", url);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return params;
}
```

And now instead of `getParams()` you need `getBody()` method:

```
@Override
public byte[] getBody() {
    try {
        return getJsonObject().toString().getBytes("utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I  replace getParams to getBody and test your solution now I get this W/System.err: com.android.volley.TimeoutError

Comment: Probably `TimeoutError` means that it took longer than the website's server was prepared to wait (your connection with the website "timed out."). When I'm sending this request from postman (now) it takes 20 (twenty!) seconds. So, so long.

Comment: OK as you said I change timeout in DefaultRetryPolicy to 30sec like what company said and its work now